# Density of Lipschitz functions on $C^0_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, lipschitz-functions, approximation-theory

**My problem:**

Suppose
$$V=C^0_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})= \{ f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | f \mbox{ is continuous and bounded}\}$$
with the usual norm $\|.\|_{\infty}$. I am asking if
$$W= \{ f \in V | f \mbox{ is Lipschitz continuous }\}$$
is dense or not in $V$.

**Attempt:**

I tried using convolution but it is NOT true that:
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0}  \| \rho_{\varepsilon}*f - f \|_{\infty} = 0$$

because it is true only if $f \in L^p$ where $p<+\infty$.

Comment: Take any bounded continuous function that is not uniformly continuous as a counterexample.

Comment: @PhoemueX thank you very much!

Comment: @PhoemueX I have just noticed that I did not understand why this is a counterexample, could you please explain me what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I will leave it to you to prove each of the following statements:

1. Every Lipschitz continuous function is uniformly continuous.
2. The uniform limit of uniformly contiuous functions is again uniformly continuous.
3. Thus, a function that is not uniformly continuous cannot be uniformly approximated by Lipschitz functions.

Thus, if there exists a bounded, continuous function which is not uniformly continuous, then the set of Lipschitz functions is not dense.

Such a function indeed exists, e.g. for
$$
f : \quad \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto \sin(2 \pi \cdot x^2)
$$
and arbitrary $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we have that $f(n) = \sin(2 \pi n^2) = 0$, but
$$
f \Big( n + \frac{1}{8 n} \Big)
= \sin \bigg( 2 \pi \Big(n^2 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{64 n^2} \Big) \bigg)
= \sin \Big( \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{32 n^2} \Big)
\to 1
\quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$
This easily shows that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.